# Fetching call logs in android

Tags: android, telephonymanager, calllog

while fetching call logs then how to show that the call is made by one side has picked by other side or not attended or cancelled.I have tried **CallLog**,**TelephonyManager** classes of android to find the call logs but on different devices, the results are different.

> > In my Samsung phone when someone call me and if I disconnected the call then in my call log, type of call is showing null.
> >
> > In my Gionee phone when someone call me and if I disconnected the call then in my call log, type of call is showing incoming with duration=0sec.
> >
> > In my HTC phone when someone call me and if I disconnected the call then in my call log, type of call is showing Missed.

I want any generic thing for all android devices, showing the same results.

I am very frustrated.I am a newbie. I am finding everywhere on google but no result found please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got to know that these things depends upon the brand of the device.

For making the app working with all the brands, I need to write code for every single brand like Samsung,HTC etc. after checking their response regarding call missed/cut.